# How do I redirect only www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/join

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to reditect only www requests to my landing page. I have tried with 301 www to mydomain.com/join but it keeps sending all pages to homes. I would rather forwards www to join, but leave mydomain.om requests to go to mydomain.com/home

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ join [R=301,L]

Usage = These rules will redirect only [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) to mydomain.com/join